# Responsiveness/@media query's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling with is the media query/responsiveness for my banner image, it won't scale down when I go to tablet or phone screen.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background: rgb(17, 17, 17);
    min-height: 200vh;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
}
header.sticky {
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
}
header .logo {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
header .logo:hover {
    color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}
header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
header ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
header ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}
.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(images/banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: .4;
}
header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a {
    color:#000
}
.h1 {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
width: 80%;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
}

.image1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 19px;
}

/* about me */
.about {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 78px 0px;
    background-color: #191919;
}
.about img {
    height: 800px;
    width: 520px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
@media (max-device-width: 500px) {
    .about img {
        padding-right: 20px;
        height: 500px;
    }
}
.about-text {
    width: 550px;
}
.main {
    width: 1130px;
    max-width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.about-text h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}
.about-text h5 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.about-text p {
    color: #fcfc;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
button {
   background: #f9004d;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 2px solid transparent;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 13px 30px;
   border-radius: 30px;
}
button:hover {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #f9004d;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.name {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fcfc;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}



/* footer */
footer {
    height: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    font-family: "poppins";
    padding-top: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(17, 17, 17);

}
.footer-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-content h3 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
.footer-content p {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.socials {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
}
.socials li {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.socials a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.socials a i {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    transition: color .4s ease;
}
.socials a:hover i {
    color: #000;
}
.footer-bottom {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px 0;
   background: #000;
   text-align: center;
}
.footer-bottom p {
    font-size: 14px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.footer-bottom span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: .4;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>enDURANCE FIT, Andrea Durance Personal Trainer</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   <header>
     <a href="#" class="logo">enDurancefit</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#aboutme">About Me</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Testimonies</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
     </ul>
   </header>
   <section class="banner">
   </section>
   <h1 class="h1">Welcome To enDurance fit <p style ="font-family: Rajdhani">Andrea Durance</p><p>Personal Trainer</p> </h1>
  </div>


  <!--Section 2: About me-->
<section class="about" id="aboutme">
  <div class="main">
    <img src="images/profile.jpg">
   <div class="about-text">
     <h1>About Me</h1>
     <h5>Personal Trainer <span style="color: #f9004d;"> & Fitness Instructor</span></h5>
     <p>I have 5 years’ experience within the fitness industry, firstly as a level 2 fitness instructor, then a level 3 personal trainer, also teaching various classes along the way, including spin, kettlebells and bootcamps. 
      My passion for fitness began in my early teens around the age of 13-14.
      <p> This is where my aspirations to become a personal trainer began, and not long after that is when my career began. The manager of the gym where I was training at the time recognised my passion and offered me work experience, which led on to an apprenticeship in which I gained my fitness instructing qualification. Leading on from this I completed my level 3 personal training through a different apprenticeship based at another gym.</p>
      <p>A funny fact about the name of my company ‘enDurancefit’, is that I first came up with it when I was about 14, and I was dead set that one day I will have a personal training business and I wanted it to be called enDurancefit, and here we are! Moral of the story, if you have a goal, stick at it and don’t lose sight of it no matter the setbacks you may encounter! </p>
      <p>Training and exercise not only keeps me physically well, but mentally well also. One of the many reasons I love it, one of my aims is to help my clients keep physically and mentally well with a combination of positive coaching and lifestyle changes. 
      <p>Training and exercise is more than just the physical results, of course seeing muscle growth/fat loss/weight gain or loss depending on the goal is always something to be proud of. But for most people training becomes their ‘me’ time, time to forget life’s stresses and a time to focus on you, your goals and your own health and wellbeing.
      I want to help my clients reach a happy, healthy, and sustainable lifestyle, training to their maximum capabilities and smashing goals set, also whilst enjoying life.</p> 
      <p>FITTER, HEALTHIER, STRONGER, AND HAPPIER. 
      enDurancefit <br>
      <div class="name" > ANDREA DURANCE </div> 
      </p>
      <button type="button">Contact Me</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>














<section>
 <footer class="footer-content">
      <div>
        <h3>enDurancefit</h3>
        <p>Thank you for visiting, dont forget to check out my socials.</p>
        <ul class="socials">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <p>Copyright &copy;2021 enDurance fit. designed by <span>Andrew Hinkley</span></p>
      </div>
 </footer>
</section>

</body>


<!--Scripts-->
<!--Script for nav bar-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
  })
</script>
<!--Scrip End-->


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well done Andrew. The problem is that you've fixed both the height and width for your image. You can try fixing one of them, not both. And also `object-fit: cover;` helps keeping the aspect ratio.

```
img {
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

or

```
img {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ive fixed it. i really appreciate the help once again. Have a lovely Christmas :D